# Dynamic "magit" Git executable depending on environment in Emacs lisp

Tags: linux, macos, emacs, elisp

I use Git on my 2 Macs, which each have a different executable path (one is homebrew, one is make/install'd). I also use Git via Tramp mode.

So basically I want this, in pseudo code:

```
if home mac:
    (setq magit-git-executable "~/Projects/homebrew/bin/git")
else if work mac:
    (setq magit-git-executable "/usr/local/git/bin/git")
else [if in tramp mode]:
    (setq magit-git-executable "git") ;; Linux can work this out so don't need a full path
```

This would all work fine as the last clause if Emacs would respect my `setenv("PATH")` configuration, but it doesn't seem to.

Is there a good way to solve this in Elisp so my `emacs.d` can remain portable between machines? Failing that, is it possible to set a variable just when I'm editing a file via tramp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's going to be tricky if you insist on `magit-git-executable` taking one value if you're in a Tramp buffer and another value if not. It would be easier to leave `magit-git-executable` at its default value of `"git"`, and adjust your `exec-path` depending on which machine you're on.

How do you distinguish your machines? By name? If so, then maybe something like this:

```
(require 'cl)
(loop for (name . dir) in '(("home.local" . "~/Projects/homebrew/bin")
                            ("work.local" . "/usr/local/git/bin"))
      if (string= (system-name) name)
      do (push dir exec-path))
```

Comment: Assuming I leave it as "git", how do I get Emacs to respect my path? The only reason I have full paths is because it doesn't seem to like my setenv("PATH") stuff.

Comment: The `PATH` environment variable only affects programs that are launched via a shell. When programs are launched directly (e.g. via `call-process` or `process-file`) it's the `exec-path` list that is searched. The `magit` extension launches git via `process-file`, so it's `exec-path` that you need to set.

Comment: ``exec-path`` was the answer. Thanks very much!